# Removing children from Array inside ScrollView always deletes last item

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} >
  {this.state.images.map((uri,i) => 
  <Thumb key={i} number={i} uri={uri} onDelete ={this.deleteImage.bind(this)} /> )}
</ScrollView>
```

Here each `Thumb` class has `Image`. Whenever I click on the image it is required to be deleted from the `ScrollView`.

My Thumb component looks like this

```
 class Thumb extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    show : false
  }
}


  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(nextProps,'nextprops')
    return false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.button ]}>


            <View style={[{position:'relative'},styles.img]} >
              <View style={{position:'absolute'}}>
                <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri:this.props.uri.path}}/>
              </View>

              <View style={[styles.img , {position:'absolute',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',opacity:1}]}>

              <TouchableHighlight onPress = {() => {this.props.onDelete(this.props))}}>
                <Icon name="close" size = {30} color="white"/>
                 </TouchableHighlight>
              </View>
            </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and i'm trying to delete

```
deleteImage(deleteProp){
//  console.log(_scrollView)
//  _scrollView.props.children.splice(deleteProp.number,1)
//  console.log(_scrollView)
  console.log(deleteProp,'prop from delete method');
   console.log(this.state.images ,'before')
 let images = this.state.images;
 console.log(images.splice(deleteProp.number ,1),'splice data');
  this.setState({images : images});
 console.log(this.state.images,'after')
  if(this.state.images.length == 0 ){
    this.setState({loading:false})
  }
}
```

How should I achieve this?

I tried deleting the corresponding state wise Image object but its always deletes the last image of the ScrollView(or last Thumb component).

I'm new to react-native and Android I don't know this is possible with ScrollView. Please suggest me the correct method.

Comment: Can you post the code to delete the entry from state.images? Normally you want to pass the index/id of the item you want to delete, like ```this.deleteImage.bind(this, i)```, so that you know which one to delete.

Comment: @fabio.sussetto i'm passing the index to delete the image

Comment: @fabio.sussetto  let images = this.state.images;
 images.splice(deleteProp.number ,1);
  this.setState({images : images});

Comment: A few things: 1) ```splice``` mutates the content of this.state.images in place. In React you should never mutate the state directly, use Array#slice instead.  2) how are you updating deleteProp? please post the full component class if you can so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @fabio.sussetto i have updated the code...

Comment: @fabio.sussetto were you able to find mistakes..sorry to bother you...i was in need of this to be working...in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue with confusing the role `keys` play in Components. We think of keys just as a unique identifier for the dynamically generated components. But it also serves as a means for React to know which components need to be redrawn.

As such, I would advise changing your `key` to be something unique to the image itself, not the position.

```
<Thumb key={uri.path} number={i} uri={uri} onDelete={this.deleteImage.bind(this)} />
```

[Here's the official docs on `keys`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys).

> The key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique. As a last resort, you can pass item's index in the array as a key. **This can work well if the items are never reordered**, but reorders will be slow. (emphasis mine).

[This is another good article about why keys are important](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/react-dot-js-and-dynamic-children-why-the-keys-are-important/).

Also, when you have arrays that are generating components, I like to "preload" the functions to not need indexes, ids, etc, passed up to it.

```
// original component
<Thumb key={i} number={i} uri={uri} onDelete={this.deleteImage.bind(this)} />
// updated function by adding index to bind params and unique key
<Thumb key={uri.path} number={i} uri={uri} onDelete={this.deleteImage.bind(this,i)} />
```

That way, when you want to delete you can simply call `this.props.onDelete()`. Just a preference but I think it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**Thumb**:

```
class Thumb extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show : false
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        console.log(nextProps,'nextprops')
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.button ]}>
                <View style={[{position:'relative'},styles.img]} >
                    <View style={{position:'absolute'}}>
                        <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri:this.props.uri.path}}/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.img , {position:'absolute',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',opacity:1}]}>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress = {this.props.onDelete}>
                            <Icon name="close" size = {30} color="white"/>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

---

**ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} >
    {this.state.images.map((uri,index) => 
    <Thumb key={index} uri={uri} onDelete={this.deleteImage.bind(this, index)}/> )}
</ScrollView>
```

---

**deleteImage()**

```
deleteImage(index) {
    const images = this.state.images;
    const newImages = [...images.slice(0, index), ...images.slice(index + 1, images.length)];
    let newState = { images: newImages };

    if(images.length === 0){
        newState = { ...newState, loading: false };
    }

    this.setState(newState);
}
```